# Creating arrays from long table structure

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have 24MM rows of data that look like this:

```
event_date  event_id    incoming_event_id
2018-12-21  A1          A2
2019-07-20  A2          A3
2018-03-21  B1          B2
2016-08-09  C1          C2
2017-04-02  C2          C3
2018-11-10  C3          C4
```

What I want to do is create an array for each grouping of events.  In this case they would look like:

```
 event_groups
[A1, A2, A3]
[B1, B2]
[C1, C2, C3, C4]
```

The lengths of these arrays could go on for a while, I suspect up to 100.  What is the most efficient way of going about doing this?

Comment: First, what is the format of your initial data? And second, please be more specific about how you want to format your data.

Comment: What additional detail are you looking for exactly?  The initial table is three columns wide (one date, two strings).  I would like ending format to either be one column wide of arrays or an array of arrays.

Comment: @toromond I am specifically looking for what the structure you're expecting this array of arrays to have, as in where you want the specific data elements from the old set to be placed into the new set.

Comment: It does not matter where they are placed in the new set, just that they are in a set together.